# How to change value of the next empty cell in a column?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to input a value into the next empty row in a column.

I tried using `rows.count` and off setting it like you would with a paste but it doesn't work. I was able to get it to change the value in the first cell but not to look for the next empty and change its value.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wbCount As Workbook
    Set wbEntry = ThisWorkbook

    wbEntry.ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Copy

    Set wbCount = Workbooks.Open("U:\MO# Count.xlsm")

    Worksheets("Golf Cart").Paste _
      Destination:=Worksheets("Golf Cart").Range("V5")

    Worksheets("Golf Cart").Range("C2").Value = 1

    wbEntry.Activate

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    wbEntry.ActiveSheet.Range("O1").Select

End Sub
```

What I have works except for not searching for the next empty cell in "C" and changing the value to "1".

Comment: Will you describe in plain words, what do you want to achieve? e.g. Copy cell `B3` to workbook `MO# Count.xlsm`  sheet `Golf Cart` column `V`. I am not able to understand your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused, why would you think it searches for an empty cell?

Leaving the rest of the macro alone for now, this line:

```
Worksheets("Golf Cart").Range("C2").Value = 1
```

Does not search for an empty cell, it just writes a "1" into Cell C2. If you would like it to find the first empty cell in column C and then write a 1 into it, then this should do the trick:

```
Worksheets("Golf Cart").Cells(Sheets("Golf Cart").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3) = 1
```

I'm not sure thats what you want tho, please clarify. This finds the last used row in column C and then goes to the next one down to write a "1" into it. It doesnt work if you want to find empty cells in an otherwise value-filled column. But you wrote something about rows.count or something, so I thought I'd post that way?